# restore SVN history for deleted directory

Tags: svn, history, restore

The situation, and it's history:

R1.) /project/path contains a lot of the files and directories, with logs

R2.) /project/path was deleted a year ago.

R3.) Replaced via add, with local copy of /project/path. (40% of files are unchanged, else deleted)

R4.) Year after, /project/path has a lot of changes, with logs

---

Now we want to restore R1 + R4 logs history for those files in /project/path.

Is any possible ways to do this ? Unfortunately I have not found the way to do this.

---

UPDATE:

The end result should be R4 file set, but with R1 + R4 logs.
Currently we need to review logs in both R1, R4.

Comment: The problem i have is to understand why you would like to restore the history? The history exists in SVN, but it looks like you like to undo the changes you have made?

Comment: No I don't want to undo something, history is needed to track changes in the files.

Answer (score 0):

First, to simplify your like you can make a copy of R2 path with -r (revision) to some new location: /project/old_path . Now you can deal with that path as any other branch.

Then merge with R4 either with svn merge or manually by looking at each file of the two versions and adding/diff/merge what you need.

From the point of view of svn the `old_path` directory and `path` from R4 are not much more related than any other two paths. svn can not know what parts of the two revisions should be used.

You can also use -r directy with svn merge: ( http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.merge )

If you explain on more detail what kind of merge effect you would like you may get a better answer.

Comment: Why are you using such an old documentation link: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.merge (that's more up-to-date).

Comment: @khmarbaise, ok fixed. The whole point is to use -r. It's not that clear what step OP has troubles with.

Comment: We already created /project/old_path used to look for previous history. But it's not a best approach, to look for comments in 2 branches. The end result should be R4 file set, but with R1 + R4 log.

Comment: svn copy the files you need into path. you can not have two conflicting file histories in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
svn help co
checkout (co): Check out a working copy from a repository.
usage: checkout URL[@REV]... [PATH]
```

Note @REV in URL - because SVN is VCS (version control system), it have data about any and all old revisions.

If R4 is current state, you can checkout in any new location old revision (R2-1), where old content still exist